# Selecting Frames in Qt

Tags: qt4

I would like for a user to be able to "delete" a frame from a series of frames in a vertical layout using the delete/backspace keys on the keyboard, but I do not know how to make it so that a frame is selectable. Does any one know of a way to do this (in C++)?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: by "stacked frames" do you mean "stacked widget"? or do you mean a series of QFrames inside a QStackedWidget, or something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Derive a new class from QFrame. Then implement some member functions according to your needs. For example, if you want to select the frame with mouse, implement [mousePressEvent](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.6/qwidget.html#mousePressEvent) and if you want to process the delete key, implement [keyPressEvent](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.6/qwidget.html#keyPressEvent).

Note that you must handle displaying the frame selection by yourself, for example by changing the frame background color.